# Diy capacitive level measures sensor

Tags: capacitive

I am trying to build an capacitive level measures sensor. I am new to this and if anyone can guide me in the right direction for a breakout card and so on.

Requires:

1. The size of measure level are between 100-500ml.
2. And level of sensitivity 0.5ml.
3. Out level signal needs to be converted to an analog signal from low to high.

I like this project 
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/team-protocentral/non-contact-capacitive-liquid-level-sensing-using-fdc1004-9333c7

My idea is to get the signal from this in though the microphone line-in and measure the volume strength and then code so I get the volume amount.

Comment: TI has an app note: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu736a/tidu736a.pdf

Comment: What is a "capacitive volume measures sensor"? What does "messing volume" mean?

Comment: Cap. Sensors measure height of fluid, but you must convert to volume

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/482286/capacitive-level-sensing-breakout-chip you are asking the same question here. for a hobbyist, the solutions available is very very inaccurate if your error tolerance is only 0.5 mL. You have to relax the precision.. any thing in that range is only possible with more $$$$ cost.

Comment: I did update my question. Please look.

Comment: The linked circuit is a level sensor rather than a volume sensor. You did not explain what "messing volume" is in your edit. I can't see anything in that article that converts the level sense signal into an audio signal suitable for a microphone input.

Comment: aa true it do measuring level but I can convert it to volume. My mistake, will update my question. I know it do not say anything about how to convert sense signal to a audio signal, maybe you know how to do it?

Comment: I note from TI application note that "This TI Design has a sensitivity resolution of <1mm based on the guidelines above", but I didn't see what kind of repeatability it has, now how well the calibration endures.  If it was me I'd be considering using electronic scales as the base sensor, as it is straightforward to get the accuracy you're after.

Comment: Yes, I believe that I can design the bottle to higher the sensitivity level. And a electronic scales is a good idea but I can't use it in this project.

Comment: I've personally built a level sensor using that very same TI app note.  Even though I have been an EE for a couple decades I found it very challenging to get working.  In the end I went with a mass based system using a strain gauge, as I was never able to get sub-mL resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The type of liquid to be measured is important, since capacitance depends on the dielectric constant. Water, being a polar molecule, has a very high value and is easy. Something like octane much less so.

Assuming water, you need a large area for the electrodes to give you a decent capacitance especially when the fluid level is low. Maybe use concentric metal pipes, perhaps stainless steel since water is quite corrosive. Then treat the whole thing as an input capacitor to your microphone, feeding it with a high frequency signal, maybe 10kHz for starters and see whether you can pick it up.

Most of this is experimental physics, with the emphasis on "experiment"